# How to compute a databasefield with the field-id

Tags: python, web2py

Model:

```
db.define_table('orders',
    Field('customer_id', db.customer)
    Field('order_id', 'string')
    )
```

I want to get a special `order_id` like `XY-150012` where `XY` is part of the customer name, `15` is the year and `12` the id the actual record-id of `orders`. I tried in the model:

```
db.orders.order_id.compute = lambda r: "%s-%s00%s" % (db.customer(r['customer_id']).short, str(request.now.year)[2:], r['id'])
```

The `id` is never recognized, the computation ends up as `None`. If I remove `r['id']` from the compute-line it works.

### EDIT:

After adding an extra field `field('running_number', 'integer')` to the model I can access this fields content.
Is there a easy way to set this fields `default=db.orders.id`?

## SOLUTION:

With Anthony´s Input, and reading about [recursive selects](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Recursive-selects) I came up with this solution:

```
db.define_table('orders',
    Field('customer_id', db.customer),
    Field('order_id', 'string', default = None))

def get_order_id(id, short):
    y = str(request.now.year)[2:]
    return '%s-%s00%s' % (short, y, id)

def set_id_after_insert(fields,id):
    fields.update(id=id)

def set_order_id_after_update(s,f):
    row = s.select().first()
    if row['order_id'] == None:
        s.update_naive(order_id=get_order_id(row['id'], row['customer_id'].short)
    else:
        return

db.orders._after_insert.append(lambda f,id: set_id_after_insert(f,id))
db.orders._after_update.append(lambda s,f: set_order_id_after_update(s,f))
```

Comment: The `fields` object passed to the `_after_insert` callback is just a dictionary of the field values used in the insert, so updating it will have no effect on the database record. So, your `_after_insert` callback won't actually update the database record.

Comment: Also, in your `_after_update` callback, there is no need to reconstruct the compute function -- you can just call it directly using `db.orders.order_id.compute()`.

Comment: Note, there is no need to use lambda functions when specifying the callbacks. You use lambda functions when you haven't defined a separate function and just need a short one-liner. In your case, you have defined separate functions, so just use those directly: `db.orders._after_update.append(set_order_id_after_update)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the record ID is not known until after the record has been inserted in the database, as the `id` field is an auto-incrementing integer field whose value is generated by the database, not by web2py.

One option would be to define an [`_after_insert` callback](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#callbacks-on-record-insert--delete-and-update) that updates the `order_id` field after the insert:

```
def order_after_insert(fields, id):
    fields.update(id=id)
    db(db.order.id == id).update(order_id=db.order.order_id.compute(fields))
db.order._after_insert.append(order_after_insert)
```

You might also want to create an `_after_update` callback, but in that case, be sure to use the `update_naive` argument in *both* callbacks when defining the `Set` (see above link for details).

Depending on how the `order_id` is used, another option might be a [virtual field](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#New-style-virtual-fields).

Comment: Thanks again Anthony - you pushed me in the right direction, although I could not exactly apply the solution you provided. See update.

Comment: What problem did you have with the above solution?

Comment: I just could not get it working. But after reading your comments I will give it another try and change the model according to your solution and see if I can figure out what the main problem was. Thanks up to now!